# How to register a Custom Form with Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

In **admin_forms.py** I've written the following code:

```
class AdminForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    question = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    q_active = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)
    option = forms.CharField()
    option_active = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)
```

I want it get registered with Django Admin, so in my **admin.py**, I've written

```
from api.admin_forms import AdminForm
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form = AdminForm
    fieldsets = (
        ('Category', {
            'fields': 'category'}),
        ('Question', {'fields': ('question', 'q_active')}),
        ('Answer Option', {'fields': ('option', 'option_active')}),
        ('Selected Answer', {'fields': ('user_role', 'answer')}),
    )
admin.site.register(EntryAdmin)
```

Definitely, this is not how we can make it work. help please!

Answer (score 7):

You should set [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) instead of `add_form`.

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminForm
    ...
```

When you register your model admin, you must provide the model as the first argument:

```
admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

`ModelAdmin` does not have an attribute `add_form`, so setting it has no effect. The [`UserAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/80b7e9d09f2d23209b591288f9b2cf3eb3d927c8/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L41) has an `add_form` attribute, which is used when adding new users.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but its not gonna work. TypeError: 'RenameBaseModelAdminMethods' object is not iterable.

Comment: That's a separate issue. You are calling `admin.site.register()` incorrectly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think i couldn't put my question the right way. I intended to use a single view to add/edit my models and wanted to achieve this using the above method and **didn't define a model** for my **AdminForm**.However, i learnt that we can't achieve this using current strategy. I used **django TabularInline** to achieve this.